# MAVEN deploy snapshot package replace the SNAPSHOT in path, not package name, with timestamp

Tags: maven, snapshot

I am using mvn deplouy:deploy-file to deploy local SNAPSHOT package to remote repository. However, the upload repository path replace the version `SNAPSHOT` with timestamp.

I was use this:

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=com.zhouyi.classifier -DartifactId=devcloud -Dversion=2.2.3SNAPSHOT -Dclassifier=source -Dpackaging=jar -DrepositoryId=snapshots -Dfile=filepath\antlr\antlr\2.7.2\antlr-2.7.2.jar -Durl=http://address:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/
```

For example:

> Uploading: http://address:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/com/zhouyi/classifier/devcloud/2.2.320181207.014307-3/devcloud-2.2.320181207.014307-3-source.jar 
>   Uploaded: http://address:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/com/zhouyi/classifier/devcloud/2.2.320181207.014307-3/devcloud-2.2.320181207.014307-3-source.jar (748 kB at 3.8 MB/s)
>   Uploading: http://address:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/com/zhouyi/classifier/devcloud/2.2.320181207.014307-3/devcloud-2.2.320181207.014307-3.pom
>   Uploaded: http://address:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/com/zhouyi/classifier/devcloud/2.2.320181207.014307-3/devcloud-2.2.320181207.014307-3.pom (410 B at 4.1 kB/s)
>   Downloading: http://address:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/com/zhouyi/classifier/devcloud/maven-metadata.xml

Maven Version is:
`Apache Maven 3.5.4 (1edded0938998edf8bf061f1ceb3cfdeccf443fe; 2018-06-18T02:33:14+08:00)`

Settings file:

```
<profile>
            <id>MyProfile</id>
            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <id>releases</id>
                    <url>http://address:8081/nexus/content/repositories/release/</url> 
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </releases>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>false</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                </repository>
                <repository>
                    <id>snapshots</id>
                    <url>http://address:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>                    
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>false</enabled>
                    </releases>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                </repository>
            </repositories>
        </profile>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the correct behaviour. The suffix `SNAPSHOT` is replaced by a timestamp when you upload the artifact to a repository.

You do not need to worry about it. You actually won't notice it in Maven because every dependency on `1.2.3-SNAPSHOT` will be resolved against the latest timestamp version.

It is only interesting if you want to reference a specific timestamp version. Then you can put that version into your pom.xml. But this normally not recommended.

Comment: But I cannot download this package via specified GAV in pom file like `<dependency> <groupId>com.zhouyi.classifier</groupId>  <artifactId>devcloud</artifactId><version>2.2.3SNAPSHOT</version> </dependency>`. I found that, Maven would search this package in **releases repository** firstly, then search in group repository, never search in snapshots repository. The download url like this: https://address/01/nexus/content/repositories/releases/com/zhouyi/classifier/devcloud/2.2.320181207.094610-1/devcloud-2.2.320181207.094610-1.pom.

Comment: Two things: 1. usually you put a - before SNAPSHOT, i.e. write 2.2.3-SNAPSHOT instead of 2.2.3SNAPSHOT. But I do not know whether this causes technical problems. 2. There might also be problems in the settings.xml, like wrong mirrors, repository lists, not activated profiles...